# MS Access 32bit with 64bit JVM

Tags: java, ms-access-2010

I am trying to connect to MS Access 32bit using 64bit JVM. It gives me following error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

This has already been addressed in several questions and the possible solution is to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

But which file I should download of the two - AccessDatabaseEngine.exe or AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe?

I am using JDK7u25 64bit with MS Access 2010 32bit on Windows7 64bit os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a Jet/ACE ("Access") database directly from another application the "bitness" of the ODBC driver must match the "bitness" of the application. So, to connect from a 64-bit Java application you need to have the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") installed. Therefore, for your current configuration you would need to install `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe`.

While in theory it *shouldn't* really matter whether the version of the Microsoft Access **application** is 32-bit or 64-bit, in many cases the 64-bit ACE installer will abort if it finds 32-bit versions of Microsoft Office applications on the machine. If that happens then you will need to do one of two things:

1. Replace the 32-bit version of Access with the 64-bit version, or
2. Switch to a 32-bit Java environment.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried to install ACE 64bit (ccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe), it doesn't allow me to go ahead as I already had 32bit MS Access. I then uninstalled MS Office 32bit, installed 64bit ACE and then tried to re-install MS Office 32bit, but now I cannot install Office 32bit. So as you said already are there only two above listed options?

Comment: @ParagJ Yes, in my experience the two options in my answer are the only two available. As it stands now, having 32-bit Office applications on a machine essentially prevents 64-bit applications from accessing Jet/ACE databases.

Comment: Ok thanks. But just one more point. I just came across this link- http://officepreview.microsoft.com/en-us/support/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA102840825.aspx So using MS Access 64-bit is not a good solution?

Comment: @ParagJ As mentioned in the article you cited, Microsoft currently recommends installing the 32-bit version of Access mainly to ensure compatibility with third-party controls and add-ons for Access that require a 32-bit application environment. You will have to decide whether or not such compatibility is a significant concern in your particular environment.